# What is -s flag in the timeit module in Python?

Tags: python

From Python Cookbook

```
python timeit.py -s"import random" -s"x=range(100000); random.shuffle(x)" "sorted(x)"
10 loops, best of 3: 152 msec per loop
```

What does the `-s` flag do?
Searched online, python help and SO. But did not find a good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From Python's built-in `help()`

```
>>>import timeit
>>>help(timeit)

....
Command line usage:
    python timeit.py [-n N] [-r N] [-s S] [-t] [-c] [-h] [--] [statement]

Options:
  -n/--number N: how many times to execute 'statement' (default: see below)
  -r/--repeat N: how many times to repeat the timer (default 3)
  -s/--setup S: statement to be executed once initially (default 'pass')
....
```

Comment: Or see the documentation at http://docs.python.org/library/timeit.html#command-line-interface

Answer (score 1):

Rereading the docs, it may be the "executed once initially" phrasing that isn't as clear as it could be (i.e. nowhere does the documentation say why being able to do that is a useful feature).

The benefit of the `-s` setup lines is that they are executed outside the timing loop, but the code inside the timing loop can *see* values that they define.

So in the quoted example, only the `sorted(x)` part is timed - the actual creation of `x` occurs in the setup code beforehand.